# Swift cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm learning Swift2/iOS app development. I am confused by an error being thrown by Xcode before compiling. Here is the code throwing the error :

```
let dotpos = display.text!.rangeOfString(".")
if dotpos != nil {
    display.text = display.text!.removeRange(dotpos!)
}
```

The error thrown is (at the line "display.text = display.text!.removeRange(dotpos!)") :

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String?'

Note : display is a `UILabel` object.

Could someone point me toward the error I might have done?

Comment: `removeRange` has no return value represented by `()`

Comment: @vadian Isn't it suppose to infer the return value as `String?` since `display.text` is of type `String?` (confirmed by option+click)?

Comment: No, the method is marked as `mutating`, that means the receiver is mutated in place.

Comment: Please Help getting  SAME error


let textString = cell.streetAddLabel.text = NSString(format: "%@\n%@", (restaurant.address != nil ? restaurant.address! : ""),
                                            (restaurant.crossStreet != nil ? restaurant.crossStreet! : "")) as! NSString
        print("tt \(textString)")

 cell.streetAddLabel.text = textString // error here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to check documentation for this ([Apple swift String link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/#//apple_ref/swift/structm/String/s:FSS11removeRangeFGVs5RangeVVSS13CharacterView5Index_T_))

```
let dotpos = display.text!.rangeOfString(".")
if dotpos != nil {
    display.text!.removeRange(dotpos!)
}
```

This code will work, `removeRange` function didn't return anything, documentation said

> mutating func removeRange(_ subRange: Range)

means text mutate when you call the method on your text label.

The text change directly and you don't need to assign new value for changing it.

Comment: What has been seen now becomes obvious! Thanks!

Comment: Cool, happy coding :)